# why does the volume of a n-dimensional sphere converge to $0$ for given radius and $n \to \infty$

Tags: volume, spheres

I was playing around with the volume of n-dimensional spheres to get a better understanding of the "curse of dimensionality" and I realized that the volume of a n-dimensional sphere tends to 0 for a given radius and $n \to \infty$ Also it increases in the beginning but starts to decrease at some point.  Is there an intiution why this happens?

Recall that the volume of a n-dimensional sphere with radius $r$ is$\frac{\pi^{0.5n}}{\Gamma(0.5n+1)}r^n$

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8258/whats-a-nice-argument-that-shows-the-volume-of-the-unit-ball-in-mathbb-rn-a

Comment: In effect you are looking at the ratio of the volume of a sphere of radius $r$ and a cube of side-length $r$. But wouldn't it be more natural to compare the volume of a sphere of radius $r$ with a cube of side-length $2r$ since that cube circumscribes the sphere?